# With the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$ why isn't the solution $y=\ln(c_1 x)+c_2$

Tags: calculus

Why isn't the general solution represented as $\ln(c_1x)+c_2$ to the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$$
If the derivative of the function $\ln(cx)$ is always $\frac{1}{x} $ where $c\in {\rm I\!R}$ why is the anti derivative and the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ interpreted as $\ln\mid x\mid$? I recognise that this is quite a simple and juvenile question however, is there an explanation for this result? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $\log c_1$ can be absorbed into $c_2$.

Comment: Note  that since the domain omits $0$, the constants can be different for $x>0$ and for $x<0$. That is why $y=\ln(|cx|)$ is essentially the same are your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because logarithm accepts only positive values. If you do now want to go to complex, you add absolute value. But for differential equations notice that
$$\log (|x|) + c = \log (|x|) + \log (c') = \log (c'|x|)$$
and since constant is arbitrary we can remove absolute value

My bad, read question wrongly, You were looking why not $\log (c_1x)+c_2$
Then you are answered in comments already

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Andrew Chin in the comments, $\log c_{1}$ can be absorbed into $c_{2}$ since they are both constants.

So you have $$y=\ln(c_{1}x)+c_{2}=\ln(x)+\ln(c_{1})+c_{2}=\ln(x)+c$$

where $c=\log c_{1}+c_{2}.$